# Device for recording pic

Tags: pic, usb, serial, device

I'm following this tutorial to make my own recorder PIC18 (http://rengenharia.com.br/?p=401), but I have a problem, I do not have the component "X1" (DB9 female connector for PCB). Anyone have any suggestions to replace/manufacture this component. And I still have another problem, my laptop does not have serial port only USB. Can I use USB instead of serial? I appreciate the response.

Comment: That "X1" connector should be readily available from any electronics supplier.  The correct name for the connector is DE9, not DB9 - the E or B inicates the shell size of the connector, and the "B" shell normally hold 25 contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this programmer, I believe you have to use RS232 serial.  If you don't have a serial port on your computer, then you would have to get a USB to serial cable and use that.  Or you can emulate a USB to serial cable with a USB to serial chip and an RS232 transceiver chip.

Generally, these sorts of components can be purchased from electronics vendors like Digikey, Mouser, Sparkfun, etc.

If you're going to have to use USB, why don't you try to find a circuit that uses a USB port instead of a serial port?

Here are a few that I found offhand:

http://picpgm.picprojects.net/hardware.html#USB_PROGRAMMER

http://usbpicprog.org/

These days, I would recommend buying a cheap programmer as your first programmer so you have a 'known good' solution for getting code onto chips.  It's incredible how cheap they can be, too:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/310653023706

Comment: Ok, thank you. I am very grateful for the response!

Comment: This type of programmer is very very unlikely to work with anything but a 'real' serial port.

Comment: Yeah, it's been a while since I tried (and failed) to build my own (parallel port) PIC programmer so I wasn't completely sure how this particular design is supposed to work.  I generally just bite the bullet and buy a known good programmer and then spend my time building my own circuitry around the chip I'm using.